# saving user id in rails user-submissions-contest has many through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, relational-database

How to configure the rails controller so I can have a user post a submission in no matter what contest. When they post their user id and the contest id should be automatically appended to the submission.

I know I can do:

1. User.first.contests.create => let the user create a contest
2. Contest.first.submissions.create => create a submission in a contest (not linked to a user)
3. User.first.submissions.create => create a submission linked to a user but not to a contest
4. **I cannot do User.first.Contest.last.submissions.create** => I want to link a submission to a contest **and** to a submission.

Is there an elegant way to fix this?

The submission controller looks like this:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_submission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # the current user can only edit, update or destroy if the id of the pin matches the id the user is linked with.
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  # the user has to authenticate for every action except index and show.
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


  respond_to :html

  def index
    @title = t('submissions.index.title')

    @submissions = Submission.all
    respond_with(@submissions)
  end

  def show
    @title = t('submissions.show.title')

    respond_with(@submission)
  end

  def new
    @title = t('submissions.new.title')

    @submission = Submission.new
    respond_with(@submission)
  end

  def edit
    @title = t('submissions.edit.title')

  end

  def create
    @title = t('submissions.create.title')

    @submission = Submission.new(submission_params)
    @submission.save
    respond_with(@submission)
  end

  def update
    @title = t('submissions.update.title')

    @submission.update(submission_params)
    respond_with(@submission)
  end

  def destroy
    @title = t('submissions.destroy.title')

    @submission.destroy
    respond_with(@submission)
  end

  private
    def set_submission
      @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
    end

    def submission_params
      arams.require(:submission).permit(:reps, :weight, :user_id)
    end

    def correct_user
      @submission = current_user.submissions.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to submissions_path, notice: t('submissions.controller.correct_user') if @submission.nil?
    end

end
```

I have following models:

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions
  has_many :users, through: :submissions

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contest

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions
  has_many :contests, through: :submissions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making this a bit complicated.

Submission is POSTED within Contest, Submission needs to know the user_id.

```
<%= simple_form_for :submission, url: contest_submissions_path(contest) do |f| %>
                  ...
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

And on your submissions CREATE method

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @contest = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])
    @submission = @contest.submissions.new(submission_params)
    @submissions.user = current_user
    .....
  end
```

The magic happens at `@submissions.user = current_user` If you are using Devise, it is easy to pass in the current_user.id ANYWHERE in the controller, as I just did in the submissions controller.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it this evening. I am going to make a new action within contests containing the code you have given me. Looks simple that way. I'll keep you up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use `@submission = current_user.submissions.new(submission_params)` and `@contest = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])` in your `SubmissionsController#create`

**EDIT: I've added some details on adding a reference to `contest_id` in the `submissions` table.**

The best way I've found to tie related things together in Rails (and indeed, any relational database) is to add a reference in the child table to the parent's `id`. You can do this with a migration in Rails.

`rails g migration AddContestToSubmission contest:references`

And modify the migration file generated in your `db/migrate/<datetime>_add_contest_to_submission` to look similar to:

```
class AddContestToSubmission < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :submissions, :contest, index: true
  end
end
```

Then go ahead and look at your `submissions` table in your `schema.rb`. You should notice something like `t.integer  "contest_id"` You should probably also add the `user_id` in your migration is you want a submission to be tied to one `user`.

Comment: I don't think I can use params[:contest_id] in the submission create because when I click the create button the params of the submission are shown and not the ones of the contest. There is a contest show view which lists all submissions per contest.

Comment: @Christoph I've got a similar setup for one of my applications, but I've got the equivalent to `submissions` nested within `contests`. Have you added a reference to `contest` in your `submission` table?

Comment: Nick, any chance you have it hosted on github somewhere so I can have a look? I have the contest id in my submission table but I am looking for a way to write it. I think It's best to do that in the controller or model and not in the view but I am wondering how.

Comment: Yes, feel free to check it out. https://github.com/nickdb93/QwesteraCONNECT The structure is that an App has many Elements (as well as comments), and each Element has many Features, all of which belong to a user.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am going to look into it.